# Which GLM(M) to use for proportional data?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I have proportional data that takes any value from 0 and 1. However, there are certainly an over-abundance of 0's, and the rest of the values (there are few) tend to be close to zero.

I'm wondering with this knowledge what is the appropriate GLM to use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the denominators, i.e. how many 'trials' for each observation?

Comment: Yes I believe so. To be more specific. the rate that I'm looking at is: # of a certain type of hatches / # of pupae. 

This made me think of doing a Poisson regression model with offset or I've also heard that its possible to use proportional data in a Binomial logistic regression. 

What do you think?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know proportions and their denominators (in your case, "number of a certain type of hatches per number of pupae"), then a binomial response is (in my opinion) the most principled/sensible thing to do.

- Lots of zeros are expected when the mean proportion is low; it's still possible that you need a zero-inflated binomial model, but unlikely (Warton 2005).
- When the mean of a binomial is low, a Poisson model with an offset gives nearly identical results (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90422/poisson-vs-binomial-for-rare-events); more precisely, the probability should be low *everywhere* (e.g. if you have a few combinations of covariates that lead to higher probabilities, that could mess things up).
- As always you should check for overdispersion after fitting the model and if necessary do something appropriate (quasi-likelihood, observation-level random effects, beta-binomial model ...)

---

Warton, David I. “Many Zeros Do Not Mean Zero Inﬂation: Comparing the Goodness-of-FIt of Parametric Models to Multivariate Abundance Data.” Environmetrics 16 (2005): 275–89. https://doi.org/10.1002/env.702.

Comment: +1. To clarify something, if we use a logit we are primarily looking at a fractional logit model.